# Can't locate a file using a regular expression in NLTK

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am fairly new to programming and NLTK and have been following a text book to get started. I am having trouble getting the Regular Expression r'.*.pos' to work in Python 2.7 (Mac). I am following a set of examples in the book, Python Text Processing with NLTK 2.0 Cookbook, chapter 3. I think the code is meant to find all files named pos (or with the extension "pos" I'm not entirely sure.

Below is the code:

```
reader = TaggedCorpusReader('/Users/mattmatters22/Desktop/pos',r'.*\.pos')
reader.words()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    reader.words()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/tagged.py", line 82, in words
    for (fileid, enc) in self.abspaths(fileids, True)])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py", line 421, in concat
    raise ValueError('concat() expects at least one object!')
ValueError: concat() expects at least one object!
```

Comment: the first line of code should actually be two lines - "reader.words()" is meant to be on the next line

Comment: Have you tried adding / to the end of the path? (i.e. `/Users/mattmatters22/Desktop/pos/`)

Answer (score 0):

```
r'.*\.pos'
```

means match ".pos" with maybe something before (the `.*` part).

But this can not be found in "/Users/mattmatters22/Desktop/pos". Could this cause your problem?

Try it without the dot `r'.*pos'` and see if you get the same error or a result.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I just tried that and seem to be getting the same result. I have a folder on my desktop titled "pos" and it contains a file named "brown.pos". I'm under the impression the code is meant to access one of them somehow but it can't find them..

Comment: It really looks like there's something wrong with your path. Capitalization error perhaps? Check if `os.listdir('/Users/mattmatters22/Desktop/pos')` shows you your file.

Answer (score 0):

Try `reader = TaggedCorpusReader('/Users/mattmatters22/Desktop/pos',['brown.pos'])`
If that doesn't work, then `brown.pos` must not be in `/Users/mattmatters22/Desktop/pos`

Answer (score 0):

The code in nltk book assumes that the corpus is named brown.pos, which is not the case and doing a help(TaggedCorpusReader) and looking at its init function explains to me that I need to give two arguments - path and filename or regex which can be used to compute filename.

I tried the following on my linux system and it works. Hopefully code is self-explanatory:

```
    >>> import nltk
    >>> nltk.corpus.brown.fileids()
    [u'ca01', u'ca02', u'ca03' ..]
    >>> nltk.corpus.brown.abspath('ca01')
    FileSystemPathPointer(u'/home/<username>/nltk_data/corpora/brown/ca01')
    >>> reader = TaggedCorpusReader('/home/<username>/nltk_data/corpora/brown/', 'ca01')
    >>> reader.words()
    [u'The', u'Fulton', u'County', u'Grand', u'Jury', ...]
```

After this, instead of using explicit file name, you can substitute your own regex.